# Error al importar SvgUri

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

Estoy intentando usar una imagen .svg pero cuando la renderizo en mi componente me salta el siguiente error:

> Attempted import error: 'react-native-svg-uri' does not contain a
> default export (imported as 'SvgUri').

Mi código:

```
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';

const screenBg = require('../../src/assets/eatkube_logo.svg');

<View style={stylesLoginScreen.logoContainer}>
             <SvgUri source={screenBg}
                            width='100'
                            height='100'>
             </SvgUri>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

bueno  no estas  haceindo  un componente  como tal  :
un componente  tiene la forma

```
const myCoomponente() =>{
//funciones
return(
<View style={stylesLoginScreen.logoContainer}>
             <SvgUri source={screenBg}
                            width='100'
                            height='100'>
             </SvgUri>
</View>
);

}
```